# Fitting Iframes into Table Cells

Tags: html, css, excel, iframe

I am trying to fit a few iframes into a non-uniform html table generated by Excel (I am using Excel to cerate tables because I need to prototype 30 dashboard designs – cannot code them all now) . I have a question about table column widths and heights – and their correspondence to irfame width and height values.

When I set the iframe width and height to the pixes which are specified in HTML – the iframes do not fit in – they appear smaller than the table cells. 
Can you help me find a way to find the exact height and width of the table cells so tat I can set the iframes to perfectly fit into the table cells?
Here is the table example:

https://jsfiddle.net/a6q2jfjr/

```
<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=1088 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:1088pt'>
    <col width=440 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:21467;width:440pt'>
 <col width=312 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:15213;width:312pt'>
 <col width=48 span=7 style='width:48pt'>
 <tr height=173 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:173.25pt'>
  <td height=173 class=xl6313155 width=440 style='height:173.25pt;width:440pt'><iframe src="https://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/100-great-css-menu-tutorials.html"width="585" height="173" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe></td>
  <td class=xl6413155 width=312 style='width:312pt'><iframe src="https://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/100-great-css-menu-tutorials.html"width="413" height="173" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe></td>
  <td colspan=7 rowspan=2 class=xl6513155 width=336 style='width:336pt; text-align: left;'><iframe src="https://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/100-great-css-menu-tutorials.html"width="336" height="500" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=324 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:324.0pt'>
  <td colspan=2 height=324 class=xl6613155 style='height:324.0pt'><iframe src="https://www.noupe.com/essentials/freebies-tools-templates/100-great-css-menu-tutorials.html"width="999" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"> </iframe></td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=440 style='width:440pt'></td>
  <td width=312 style='width:312pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>
```

BTW – I would never use Excel to create such tables but it seems to be the fastest way to create any kind of fixed layout – maybe there is a software which can cerate clean HTML in this way – by visual painting of the content blocks?

Thank you so much!

Gabriel

Comment: Why not set the width/height to 100% instead of using absolute sizes ?  And make sure there's no margin/padding on the td and iframe

Comment: interesting - that 100% setting will make the content inside iframes to stretch to fill them?

Comment: It should cuase the iframe to fit the table cell - it won't affect the *content* of the iframe: that is controlled by its own styling.

Comment: I tried setting it all to 100% and it does not work in all of the cells https://jsfiddle.net/ohd26ma8/

Comment: Your HTML seems off - the first table row has 3 cells, then the second has only one but the colspan is 2 ?

Comment: yes I guess you are right - might as well do it in dream weaver - but maybe you know any software which allows to draw html tables?

Comment: Sorry not really a WYSIWYG HTML person...